# Can this used with Arduino to send SMS to phone?

Tags: arduino, gsm

I want to know the possibility of using [this TC35 board](http://www.sainsmart.com/siemens-tc35-sms-gsm-module-voice-adapter.html) to send SMS to my phone?

If there is possibility, what about codes? Does anyone have relative codes for it?

Answer (score 4):

It is a GSM module, so yes, you can send SMS in text mode with a simple standard AT+ command:

> **AT+CMGF=1**
>
> OK
>
> **AT+CMGS="+391122222222"**
>
> > **The Quick Brown Fox... [CTRL-Z]**
>
> +CMGS: 198
>
> OK

Detailed doc on http://www.developershome.com/sms/cmgsCommand.asp and http://www.developershome.com/sms/operatingMode2.asp

It's straightforward serial communication, but if you want Arduino-specific setup/code, check [this page](http://denhart.dk/2012/01/siemens-tc35-gsm-module-arduino/).